# Issue sorting LinkedList with Item object

Tags: java, list, sorting, nodes

I have an issue creating a sort() method for my linked list.
This is my implementation of Comparable in the Item class.

```
public class Item implements Comparable <Item>{
   public Date delivered;
   public final String RFIDNR; 
   public String name;
}
public int compareTo(Item other)
   {
      return name.compareTo(other.getItemName());
   }
```

This is my sort method in my linked list class

```
public void sort()
      {
          Node node = header.next;
          Node tempNode = null;
          boolean sorted = false;
          while (!sorted)
          {
              sorted = true;
              while (node != null)
              {
                  if (node.itm.compareTo(node.next.itm) > 0) throw new NullPointerException();
                  {
                      tempNode = node.next;
                      node.next = node;
                      node = tempNode;
                      sorted = false;
                  }
                  node = node.next;
              }
          }
      }
```

What i try to do here is change position of elements that are not in ascending order and switch them. Going through the whole list until sorted = true.
I am running into NullPointerException errors.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You have ```if (...) throw new NullPointerException();``` in your code. The block below the if gets executed no matter what, and you throw a NullPointerException if this node's item is greater than the next node's item

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following code.

```
   while (node != null)  {
        if (node.itm.compareTo(node.next.itm) > 0) throw new 
                                                 NullPointerException();
            {
```

You don't check to see if `node.next` is null so you try to compare to something that isn't there when trying to access `node.next.itm`.

I can't guarantee a specific solution since you didn't post your implementation but  you need to also ensure `node.next` is not null.  Try the following:

```
   while (node != null)  {
        if (mode.next != null && node.itm.compareTo(node.next.itm) > 0) {
                //do the swapping
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using the following.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
          {
              Node node = header.next;
              Item temp = null;
              while (node.next != null) {
                  if (node.itm.compareTo(node.next.itm) > 0)
                  {
                      temp = node.next.itm;
                      node.next.itm = node.itm;
                      node.itm = temp;
                  }
                  node = node.next;
              }
          }
```